# CocoaPods with Dynamic Frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Assume the following setup:

A Swift project with a main target that links two dynamic Cocoa Touch Framework targets.

- MainProject

  - MainTarget
  - FrameworkA
  - FrameworkB

Conditions:

- Framework A links CocoaPodM.
- Framework B links CocoaPodN.
- The test target for the main target and FrameworkA require the Pod CocoaPodTestLoggingX.
- The test target for the FrameworkB requires the Pod CocoaPodTestLoggingY.

Is the following Podfile correct?

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MainTarget' do

    pod 'CocoaPodM', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'CocoaPodN', '~> 1.0'

    target 'MainTarget Tests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'CocoaPodTestLoggingX', '~> 1.0'
    end

end

target 'FrameworkA' do

    pod 'CocoaPodM', '~> 1.0'

    target 'FrameworkATests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'CocoaPodTestLoggingX', '~> 1.0'
    end
end

target 'FrameworkB' do

    pod 'CocoaPodN', '~> 1.0'

    target 'FrameworkBTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'CocoaPodTestLoggingY', '~> 1.0'
    end
end
```

To be more specific:

1. When a framework uses a Pod: Must it be linked also in the main target that uses the frameworks? Keep in mind a standalone build of the framework to be used in a different project. I assume the external Pod is physically only included in the app and not in both, the app and the framework.
2. The same question for tests when running the whole test set from the main target and all test targets are included in the scheme.